# Unable to switch to Salesforce classic from lightning

Tags: lightning-experience

I have assigned one permission set to user to enable lighting experience.

Please note `Hide Option to Switch to Salesforce Classic` is unchecked (false) and also at profile level this checkbox is false.

Still when logged in as the user, I am unable to see option to switch it to classic .

Comment: Is it happening only for that user or all users are not able to switch to classic ?

Comment: Are you using Salesforce Essentials Edition organization? In that type of organization only system admins have access to Salesforce classic.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000270223&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: @VijayGanji It is happening for all the users. Thanks!

Comment: @NishantSinghPanwar We have enterprise edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is happening for all users, then you can check if this below setting was enabled

Go to Setup > Click on **Lightning Experience Transition Assistant** > Click on **Go To Steps** on **Optimize Phase i.e. 3 step** > Open **Motivate Users to Work in Lightning Experience** section > Check if **Make Lightning Experience your org's only experience** setting is enabled

If the above setting is enabled, then disable it,  log out from Salesforce, clear your cache and history of browser and login again and then try switching back to classic.

Comment: This setting seems to be under `Turn Off Salesforce Classic for Your Org` section now (and NOT under `Motivate Users to Work in Lightning Experience` section)